# How to set the max textsize in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbd_user_pt_tag"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lbd_user_pt"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/leader_board_my_pt"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbd_user_pt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="90000"
                    android:textDirection="ltr" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Currently I have a relative layout that is the horizonal line. And there is two textview inside . Since the length of the relative layout is too small, the 2 textview overlay or behave werid

like:

[user_pt_tag user_pt]

The problem is , I would like the user pt align right and expand to left , also , the common textsize is 20sp , if the pt overlap the tag , the size will be reduce. (the pt textview is at most 5 digits , that will no more digit than that) How to achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//try to use Linear Layout rather than Relative Layout like below
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbd_user_pt_tag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/leader_board_my_pt"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbd_user_pt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="90000"
            android:textDirection="ltr" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbd_user_pt_tag"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

                    android:maxLength="5"//you can give the length as per your need 

                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lbd_user_pt"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="leader_board_my_pt"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbd_user_pt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="90000"
                    android:textDirection="ltr" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```